# Broadleaf add custom field in navigation side bar

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I want to add a new menu field to the lest navigation panel for which I followed the instructions this link

```
http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/admin/admin-custom-controllers
```

Now I am getting the following error

```
Error resolving template "admin/views" , template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured template resolvers (layout/fullPageLayout : 17)
```

Where am I doing wrong . Please advice .

Comment: Are you sure that you created this file? `admin/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/templates/admin/views/test.html`

Comment: Yes I did but was getting  a stack trace . I then created test.html in admin/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/templates/layout/partials as was given in the applicationContext-servlet-admin.xml's blAdminWebTemplateResolver bean property name prefix value . I also changed Mycontroller.java model.addAttribute("customView", "test") statements 2nd parameter to only "test" and the database table inserts were done before . Now it works fine .