# Error when add custom controller to Broadleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, broadleaf-commerce

I follow below tutorial for add custom controller to broadleaf admin console.

https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/admin/admin-custom-controllers

Then I update my code as mentioned below. Because I'm getting some updates from below links.

http://forum.broadleafcommerce.org/viewtopic.php?t=4209

[Broadleaf add custom field in navigation side bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32579457/broadleaf-add-custom-field-in-navigation-side-bar)

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/" + MyController.SECTION_KEY)
@Secured("ROLE_PERMISSION_OTHER_DEFAULT")
public class MyController extends AdminAbstractController {

    protected static final String SECTION_KEY = "test";

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) throws Exception {
        // This is expected by the modules/emptyContainer template, this is a custom template that gets included into the body
        model.addAttribute("viewType", "test");

        // ensure navigation gets set up correctly
        setModelAttributes(model, SECTION_KEY);

        // gets the scaffolding set up to display the template from the customView attribute above
        return "modules/defaultContainer";
    }

}
```

Add UI page in below path.

[image]

After run the /test every time I got the below error message.

```
2020-07-13 12:08:24.923 ERROR 17577 --- [nio-8081-exec-9] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8081-exec-9] Exception processing template "layout/fullPageLayout": Error resolving template "views/test", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (template: "modules/defaultContainer" - line 7, col 15)
```

Could you please help me to solve this issue. Any help or workarounds can be really appreciated.

Comment: The name of the template _appears_ to be `admin/views/test`.

Comment: Thanks for reply @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-. Now it's getting bellow error. "Error resolving template "views/admin/views/test", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (template: "modules/defaultContainer" - line 7, col 15)
"

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- can you help me to solve this. Above solution is not working.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I've got some tips for troubleshooting. I would use `emptyContainer` instead of `defaultContainer`, since `emptyContainer` does not modify the path to the template like `defaultContainer` does. You would need to rename `viewType` to `customView`. Then, I would add a copy of my test template to every folder in the hierarchy from `WEB-INF`. Hopefully with this method you can figure out which directory it is trying to read from. If that doesn't work, you could add a custom template resolver to resolve from whatever path you want.